# access contacts in outlook using Script lab

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, scriptlab

can Oauth be used in script lab(custom made) for authentication and can it be used to access and fetch outlook contacts ?
if yes then how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item in Outlook. So, the `ScriptLab` add-in was developed for playing with APIs for the current item (OfficeJS) and getting sample pieces of code. If you need to access other items/contacts I'd suggest using [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) instead or EWS (discontinued with a time) as well as Outlook REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !!! another thing i want to ask is that should i use SSO with yeoman generator rather than only default outlook add in project ?

Comment: It is up to you when and how to use SSO, but yeoman simplifies the process of creation add-ins.